# secure L2 connection

Tags: connection, cisco-asa, security

Due to some rapid changes I need to also provide vlan(s) in a new location. The topology looks like this:

```
(main location, vlans:id=6(workstations),id=8(phones))
  |
 my_switch01
  \
   \
    some_not_sec_switches
   /
  /
 my_switch02
  |
 (new location vlans:id=6,8)
```

I would like to secure connection between my_switch01 (hp4108GL) and my_switch02 (3com 3824). First I considered buying two ASA5505-BUN-K9 devices, but I believe they would be more useful for securely connecting two networks site-to-site (more like secure L3 connection). They have a 'transparent firewall mode' but after some reading I'm still not sure if it is possible.

Is it possible to use two ASA5505-BUN-K9 for securing connection between two switches, I call it vlan-to-vlan?

Comment: @user79720, please be specific about the security requirements (authentication, encryption, etc...) and **why**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use them as L2 firewalls but, given a choice, it would be far better to not stretch the subnets across then you can route or not, using a L3 firewall if that is required, depending on your requirements.